# How can I use thread concept for my update () function instead of root. after() ,So that it wouldn't disturb tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

Due to `root. after(200,update)`  my tkinter window feeling laggy.
I shown both encoder value and rpm , torque value on tkinter window .
My issue is I interface encoder as Interrupt and read ** RPM and torque** value via serial communication, So I need to read value in every 200 milliseconds for which I used `root. after(200,update)`.But it cause issue with encoder value (feeling sticky on tkinter window).

After googling so much threading may be the solution of this issue ,I realize .But I have no idea how to use thread concept. So I am here for assistance .

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
import pigpio
import tkinter as tk
pos=0
rpm=0
torq=0
pow=0

    def callback(way): #interrupt event sense on pin no 17,18 for encoder
        global pos
        global st
        if st == 1:
            pos += way
            if pos >= 9999:
                pos = 9999
            if pos <= 0:
                pos = 0
            var.set(pos)
            
    def rpm_update():
        global rpm
       -------------------
       -------------------  # code for read values from RPM card
       var2.set(rpm)
    def torq_update():
        global torq
        ---------------------
        ---------------------  # code for read values from torque card
        var3.set(torq)
    def pow_update():
        global rpm,torq,pow
        ----------------       # code for power calculation
        -------------------
        var4.set(pow)
    def update():
        rpm_update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        torq_update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        pow_update()
        root.after(200,update)

    path="/home/pi/logo.png"
    root=tk.Tk()
    img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    panel=tk.Label(root,image=img)
    panel.pack()
    panel.place(x=930,y=10,height=50,width=70)
    root.title("Dynalec")
    root.iconphoto(False,img)
    root.geometry("1000x600")
    
    -----------------------------
   ------------------------------      # tkinter window body 
    -----------------------------
    decoder=rotary_encoder.decoder(pi, 17, 18, callback)
    root.after(200,update)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `time.sleep` in your `update` function? That does exactly what it says: it puts the entire application to sleep.

Comment: @BryanOakley. Because I need some delay for serial data transmit and receive on RS-485 bus.

Comment: You can use `after` to call those just like you're calling the function itself. Assuming that each of these functions takes just a few ms to run, there's no need to add the overhead of threading.

Comment: @BryanOakley, you mean to say that I should use ```after``` for every function. i.e  ```root. after(100,rpm_update)```                                                                                                ```root .after(100,torq_update)```                                                                                       ```root. after(100,pow_update)```

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it. Though, if you want them to run 10ms apart then the first would be 100, the next 110.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rewrite `update()` as below:

```py
def update():
    while True:
        rpm_update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        torq_update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        pow_update()
        time.sleep(0.2) # sleep for 200ms
```

Then replace `root.after(200, update)` by `threading.Thread(target=update, daemon=True).start()`:

```py
#root.after(200,update)
threading.Thread(target=update, daemon=True).start()

root.mainloop()
```

Of course you need to import `threading` module.